# Cannot use/find a setting in physic settings

Tags: animation, mesh, texturing, objects, fluid-simulation

I'm new to blender and I'm enjoying it. You guys made it absolutely amazing.
My problem is  about some settings, I'm creating Animated rain by watching a tutorial in YouTube,
but it's on *Blender 2.8* and I'm using  *Blender 2.92*. In physic settings fluid
option the settings are different in **2 versions**, I need to change **speed, subdivision,
particle generation, and baking it after that**. I need those settings, with out it  I can't finish that part. So I need help. And I have
another problem in *rain drop size,* when rain drops the
*size of the reflection is big and they all combined together* and it doesn't seem like dropping
actually real .
I don't know what to do next.
So, What can I do for it?

I expecting answers soon as possible and other options.
If I can't do anything for the  physic setting problem,
can I open the 2.92 Blender file in 2.8 Blender?

I'm 15 and doing this project and I need to complete it or I'll get the name "Quitter"

Thank You,

Yours Sincerely,

-Arosh Adithyan

Comment: I don't think they have changed.
you should select the domain object to see those options.

Comment: and also you can open projects in other version.

Comment: 2.80 fkuid simulation was change a bit for 2.92. You could download 2.80 from the website